# Teradata Input date is out of business calendar boundaries

Tags: sql, teradata

Given a table :

```
Table : Dates
INSERTION_DATE
10/12/2016
14/10/2106
```

When I run a query that extracts the weeknumber of year for each date :

```
SELECT TD_SYSFNLIB.WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR(INSERTION_DATE) FROM DB.DATES
```

I am getting this exception :

```
SELECT Failes [9134] Input date is out of business calendar boundaries.
```

This is because Teradata doesn't seems to enjoy using this library for future dates, (14/10/2106) but I would like to do a workaround for my use case, wich is getting the weeknumber of year for a given date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are date functions in Teradata that are not tied to business calendars which may offer you more flexibility. They were introduced in TD 13.x and renamed in TD 14.x. They begin with TD_ and in your instance TD_Week_Number_Of_Year comes to mind as the candidate.

The business calendars are restricted to dates between 1/1/1900 and 12/31/2100.

Answer (score 0):

@will You can try following:

```
select to_char(INSERTION_DATE,'iyyyiw')
```

Taken from @dnoeth's post.

https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/getting-week-of-the-year-from-a-date

Answer (score -1):

The function expects a date as an argument. The mentioned values don't convert into a date by default.
Try explicit casting (or change the type in table `dates`

```
create volatile table dates  ( INSERTION_DATE char(10) ) on commit preserve rows;
insert into dates values ( '10/12/2016' );
insert into dates values ( '14/12/2016' );
SELECT
TD_SYSFNLIB.WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR(cast(INSERTION_DATE as date format 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
FROM DATES;
WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR(INSERTION_DATE,'TERADATA')
---------------------------------------------
                                           50
                                           49
```